# Mediawiki Url Rewrite For category Pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mediawiki, wiki

I am newbie to Mediawiki, I want to make my URLs short using .htaccess.

I want `/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Category1&pagefrom=Page5`

displayed as `/wiki/Category:Category1/pagefrom=Page5` in the url bar

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
#External redirect with THE_REQUEST trick; change R to R=301 when everything works correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /wiki/index\.php\?title=(.*)&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /wiki/%2/%3\? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)/(.*) /wiki/index.php?title=$1&$2 [L]
```

The above should change
`http://example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Category1&pagefrom=Page5`
to `http://example.com/wiki/Category:Category1/pagefrom=Page5`

Comment: Thanks For your answer but its display balnk because of the index.php we removed. and idea for that....?

Comment: You wanted it removed?

Comment: your  .htaccess rules right but its not proper redirect because of absance of index.php file and i wanted to remove it. how can i fix...?

Comment: Do you have the second rewrite rule added?

Comment: yas.RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: That's not my second rewrite rule?

Comment: yes i know its not your rules. but its already added in my .htaccess file